# State variables -- why is pressure one and heat not?

Tags: thermodynamics

I'm currently learning about thermodynamics, and state variables have been described as:  "a property of a system that depends only on the state that the system is in, and not how it got there."

I'm currently confused, and that definition is to too vague for it to help for me. I was told that gravitational potential energy is an example of something that isn't a state variables -- something about how it being a conservative force helping to explain it.

I can be convinced that pressure, for example, "depends only on the state that the system is in, and not how it got there", basically saying to me that the pressure can be found only needing things like temperature and volume, but not how the temperature and volume changed. That interpretation may be wrong, but it's my confused one nonetheless. And with that, I can't understand why heat, for example, or work, doesn't also apply to this.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147223/heat-and-work-are-not-the-state-functions-of-the-system-why) will help

Comment: Also: [Heat is not a noun](http://aapt.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1119/1.1341254).

Answer (score 3):

Heat is "transferred energy". You can measure the temperature at one instant (state). If you measure it again at another time and calculate the difference, you can calculate how much energy the object has gained or lost - thats heat (not a state, but a difference between two states).

The same is for work. You can measure e.g. the velocity of an object in free space which is some kinetic energy (state). If you then do some work and measure the velocity again, it has changed. But again the work done is not related to the state of the object, but to the difference between the two states.

Comment: Oh, are you saying that if I make an object go from 10 $ms^{-1}$ to $20$, I didn't do work to make it go from $0$ to $20$, I made it increase by $10$? Is that at all a correct interpretation? And if so, why is something like pressure not analogous?

Comment: @sangstar yeah, basically. If an object is already at 10 m/s it has the kinetic energy of $50*m*[m/s]$ ($E=1/2 * m * v^2$). How you managed to get there, if you accelerated the object or someone else is not relevant. If you now do work of $150*m *[m/s]$ you end up with a kinetic energy of $200*m*[m/s]$ which corresponds to a velocity of 20 m/s. It's the same for pressure, you might have some air at 1 bar in a closed container, how you get there is not relevant. Now you apply a force to shrink the container by some distance s. This is work (F*s). And you end up with e.g. 2 bar.